# Contract records access

Tags: account, sharing-rule, crud, contracts, record-access-level

Here is the sharing settings for account/contract:
[image]

Our experience users (community) have to access (read/write) the contract records under the account their contact is linked to but only those ones. The crud on the user's profile is read/create/edit enabled. Changing the sharing settings to public read/write or updating the crud to modify all won't fit here since they should access only the contracts under their company.
I wanted to update the contract__Share via apex but since contract__Share doesn't exist, it's not possible... how can this be done?

Thanks!

the crud:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So generally to set Sharings in community (Experience cloud) Sharing Sets are used.

To access sharing set settings you need to go to Setup -> Digital Experience -> Settings.

Contract is... specific. Sharing to Contract is controlled by sharing to Account (docs on Sharing Sets [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_setting_light_users.htm&type=5) -> point 6 states that.

So you need to create Sharing Set which will Share Account connected to that User... to that User.

Something like that I believe (although I've did that long time ago so play with it a little)[image]

Doing that will share Contracts to user.
If you don't want Accounts to be edited, block it using FSL/VRs for example.

Comment: It worked! Thanks @user1974566 !